# Rudin Functional Analysis Theorem 1.10

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Theorem 1.10 in Rudin's *Functional Analysis* states that

Suppose $K$and $C$ are subsets of a topological vector space, $X$. $K$ is compact and $C$ is closed, and $K \cap C = \emptyset$. Then, 0 has a neighborhood $V$ such that
\begin{equation}
(K+V)\cap(C+V) = \emptyset.
\end{equation}
In the proof of the theorem, after assuming that $K$ is non-empty, picking some $x\in K$, he proceeds to show that there exists a symmetric neighborhood $V_x$ such that $x + V_x + V_x + V_x$ does not intersect $C$. The derivation of this seems clear to me. However, then Rudin makes the following jump:

> The symmetry of $V_x$ shows then that
> \begin{equation}
> (x+ V_x + V_x) \cap (C + V_x) = \emptyset.
> \end{equation}

How is Rudin using symmetry here? I don't really understand how he gets to this line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(x+V_x+V_x) \cap (C+V_x)$ were nonempty, then there exist $v_1, v_2, v_3 \in V_x$ and $y \in C$ such that
$$x+v_1 + v_2 = y + v_3$$
But then
$$x+v_1+v_2-v_3 = y.$$
By symmetry of $V_x$, we know that $-v_3 \in V_x$ because $v_3 \in V_x$. Thus $x+v_1+v_2-v_3 \in x+V_x+V_x+V_x$ and we have a contradiction to $x+V_x+V_x+V_x$ being disjoint with $C$.